# Hosting my own service (.NET) - what is a valid response for Alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm hosting my own service (HTTPS) on Azure - I have selected 'my endpoint is a subdomain with a wildcard cert'

I'm using Alexa.NET to craft the response.

I can verify that the simulator is hitting my endpoint (I did remote debugging and saw the breakpoint was hit) and I know that my endpoint is returning this (I tried it in Postman)

```
{
    "Version": "1.0",
    "SessionAttributes": null,
    "Response": {
        "OutputSpeech": {
            "Type": "PlainText",
            "Text": "test successful"
        },
        "Card": null,
        "Reprompt": null,
        "ShouldEndSession": true,
        "Directives": []
    } 
}
```

I can't find any documentation on what the response is supposed to look like.  I guess I can try creating the same thing with a lambda function...

Anyone have any suggestions on what I can try?  This whole process of hosting my own service has been very frustrating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because my 'name's started with an uppercase.  Friggin Javascript serializer....

But thanks Vijay for the pointer to the documentation.

In .NET mvc, this is how you make the property names lower case:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alexaSkillResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find sample response format here https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#response-body-syntax

```js
{
  "version": "string",
  "sessionAttributes": {
    "string": "<object>"
  },
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "string",
      "text": "string",
      "ssml": "string"
    },
    "card": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "content": "string",
      "text": "string",
      "image": {
        "smallImageUrl": "string",
        "largeImageUrl": "string"
      }
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "string",
        "text": "string",
        "ssml": "string"
      }
    },
    "directives": [
      {
        "type": "Display.RenderTemplate",
        "template": {
          "type": "string"
    ...
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "AudioPlayer",
        "playBehavior": "string",
        "audioItem": {
          "stream": {
            "token": "string",
            "url": "string",
            "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "general": {
          "type": "VideoApp.Launch",
          "videoItem": {
            "source": "string",
            "metadata": {
              "title": "string",
              "subtitle": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "shouldEndSession": boolean
  }
}
```